# How I find the BA-equivalent booking reference for an American Airlines-managed reservation?

Tags: online-resources, bookings, seating, british-airways, american-airlines

**Note**: I do this regularly, so I am looking for a *faster* option than calling the airline on the phone - I'd like something I can do online.

I have booked a reservation with American Airlines on [aa.com](http://www.aa.com). It is ticketed and paid for, and contains an American Airlines flight and a [BA](http://www.britishairways.com/) flight. I am American Airlines Platinum (Sapphire) and the number is against the reservation. I would like to view the reservation on the BA website to change the seating, which I can't do on [aa.com](http://www.aa.com).

I know from past experience that such reservations tend to have **two** reservation codes, one for the AA portion (Sabre?) and one for the BA portion (Amadeus?). But I don't know how to find the BA code, or to display the reservation on the BA website. Entering the AA code simply gives an error that the reservation cannot be found.

How can I find the BA reservation code for this reservation, or change the seat?

Comment: The other way around (booking a flight with AA on ba.com), I remember that this was fairly easy to find out. I don't have such a booking at the moment to check though, so I can't give you more details... Maybe just book the next time with BA?

Comment: @traindriver, thanks. Wasn't an option as I used miles to pay for it. Good thought though.

Comment: Did you try to use AA booking number to login to your booking from [this page](http://www.britishairways.com/travel/managebooking/public/en_gb?eId=104001&source=MNVMMB2travel_agent_bookings)?

Comment: IkeelYou, yes. It is not recognised.

Comment: Have you added your BAEC frequent flier details to the booking on the AA website? At least sometimes, doing that causes the booking to show up in my BAEC upcoming flights list, from which I can then manage the BA legs

Comment: Ikeelyou, yep. Still no dice.

Comment: Gagravarr, I'm not a BA frequent flyer - I am an AAdvantage member.

Comment: I created a BAEC account and then, while logged into that account, went to aa.com and tried to select a seat from their site. You have to pay to actually select a seat but clicking the link is free and if you do so while you're logged into your BAEC it seems to auto-link the AA flight to your BAEC account.

Comment: Actually easy.. go to the qantas website.. manage your flight., and put in your AA locator number.. it finds your flight but repopulates your locator field with your BA locator number.. I do it all the time..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cannot guarantee it will be work in every scenario, but at least in this case, I found an answer.

It appears sometime after ticketing, the American Airlines number will work in the BA [MMB](https://www.britishairways.com/travel/managebooking) page, as suggested by IKeelYou - somewhat. I tried it again this morning and it gave me an error, stating that it couldn't find the reservation, but pre-populated the reservation number box on the error page with a different reservation code. I tried this reservation code from the MMB page, and lo and behold - my reservation!

Seems like BA's website needs some bug-fixing, but I do at least have access now.

Answer (score 16):

There are two ways, depending on the kind of BA flight you booked with AA.

If you booked the BA flight under the AA flight number, eg  *American Airlines
flight 6543, Operated by British Airways*, then all you need to do is add your British Airways Executive Club number to the booking. After a few minutes, log into your BAEC account, and look at your upcoming bookings. You'll find in there your BA booking reference for the BA legs, and will be able to select your seat, see avios to be earnt etc.

if you booked the BA flight under the BA flight number, eg *British Airways
flight BA 345*, then for some reason your BAEC details won't get passed over. What you need to do is, bizarrely, go to the [Qantas "Manage My Booking" page](http://www.qantas.com.au/travel/airlines/your-booking/global/en), and enter your American Airlines reference. Scroll down to the Seats section of the page, and you'll see something like:

> Seat selection is only available for flights operated by Qantas. To select seats and manage your booking, visit British Airways site with your booking reference #12ABCD

Then take that booking reference shown there, go to the BA website, use that with Manage My Booking, then enter your BAEC details + pick seats + see avios details + etc

In summary:

- BA flight with AA flight number - enter BAEC details, wait, see on BAEC account
- BA flight with BA flight number - give Qantas AA reference, Qantas will tell you the BA reference

Comment: As I mentioned before, I'm *not* a BA frequent flyer - although that tip could be useful for others. The Qantas one sounds intriguing though - great tip. I'll try that next time.

Comment: I've just booked a ticket with both BA and AA numbered flights operated by BA (it's complicated...), the above is how I got my two different BA references. You might almost want to join the BAEC just for this bit, then change the details back to AAdvantage after you have the details!

Comment: Hmm, I have a feeling that will make things more complicated not less (I can see my miles ending up in the wrong account)! But good thought.

Comment: Gagravarr, just tried this technique (using the Qantas) for another booking (AA mileage booking, entirely flown by BA), and it worked perfectly. Thanks for the great tip.

Comment: How on earth did you figure out the Qantas trick?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I ploughed through hundreds of irrelevant and incorrect posts on FlyerTalk, trying and failing with lots of suggestions, until I stumbled across one which actually worked!

Answer (score 7):

i found a way that seems very reliable and is entirely online, for bookings made by AA:

First, have tripcase (owned by Sabre) link to the AA-created itinerary:

1. Go to tripcase.com (you might need to create an account and log in)
2. Click **Create New Trip**
3. Enter a name for the trip in the pop-up box and click **Create**
4. Click **Link a Booking** (on the upper right)
5. Enter your last name and the AA-issued PNR in the form and click **Link**

Now, for this or any trip:

1. View the trip in Tripcase (click the trip name under "My Trips")
2. Click **Documents** on the top center
3. Click **Arranger Itinerary**

The PNRs for the operating carriers should appear at the top, right after the AA PNR.

Comment: I tried this with an American Airlines Record Locator as the PNR and got a "*You cannot link this booking because this airline does not have a TripCase partnership agreement.*" error...

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, sometime in the past few months, AA revoked whatever agreement had been in place with Sabre that provided for Tripcase access to AA-created PNRs.  It still works if the PNR was created by a travel agency or other entity, even if ticketed by AA, but it no longer works for AA-created PNRs.

Answer (score 4):

This is an addition to the thread after a long interval, and so may be anachronistic in multiple ways.

At least as of this moment, entering one's AA Record Locator into the "Booking Reference" field of www.britishairways.com --> Manage Booking --> Find Booking (along with the passenger's last name) returns the BA Record Locator in the "Booking Reference" field.  Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

This is strange that through the BA Manage My Booking tool you cannot access your reservation. According to multiple resources you should be able to access it.

These sources suggest different ways to pick a seat. BA uses Amadeus for its bookings so if this does not work on BA tools [you can try Amadeus' CheckMyTrip](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/british-airways-executive-club/1310652-getting-your-pnr-booking-reference-non-ba-flights-booked-through-ba.html), the tool made to consult an Amadeus booking to obtain your BA PNR (to be identified on its website). Another possibility is to read your e-ticket and [search for a reference to an Amadeus PNR](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/american-airlines-aadvantage-pre-consolidation/773972-seat-selection-ba-codeshare.html) (it has 6 alphanumeric characters). Finally there is a suggestion that [BA may let only oneworld Sapphire and Emerald members pick a seat](http://flyerguide.com/index.php/British_Airways_Flights_(AA)#Manage_My_Booking). And apparently [BA bookings include AA PNR when you log on BA.com](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/british-airways-executive-club/1310652-getting-your-pnr-booking-reference-non-ba-flights-booked-through-ba.html) so maybe it works also the other way around, when logging on AA.com you might find the BA PNR.

Comment: Thanks. CheckMyTrip would probably help in the *opposite* scenario, but it's the Amadeus number I *don't* have.

Comment: I have the eTicket number from the confirmation email, but it only has the American (Sabre) record locator and the (long) eTicket number.

Comment: Oh, and I *am* Sapphire. Hence the frustration :)

Comment: @AndrewFerrier OK then apparently all possible ways are explored. The last chance is to have a friend travel agent that knows Sabre and Amadeus commands and can find it...

Answer (score 3):

It's sadly true that it can be quite difficult to obtain the partner PNRs for tickets issued by AA.  Here are a few ways:

- In the itinerary email sent by AA on request, the BA
  locator should appear somewhere within the information for each BA flight, but you may have to hunt for it (see screen shot below)
- You can call AA, give the agent the AA locator, and ask for your BA
  locator
- You can call BA, give the agent your first BA flight date and number,
  and the agent can look you up by name on that flight and tell you
  your BA locator

In addition, as noted in other answers, often the BA site will accept your AA locator, but I didn't include it above because it can't be relied on to always work.

Here's a screen shot of an AA email that contains the BA locator:
[image: AA_itinerary_email]

Comment: Thanks. AA do not include a BA confirmation code in the email. In the question I mentioned I was looking for a quicker and easier way than calling.

Comment: I added a screen shot to the answer, to show where it was on one of my recent bookings.

Comment: Are you booking on AA.com? That doesn't look anything like the emails I get. Point taken though...

Comment: It's really pathetic that it's so hard to obtain the PNR for partner airlines.  The information is there; the booking airline (AA in this case) really should be sure it's always included in email and prominent places on line.

Answer (score 0):

I just came to this site and this worked for me:

I checked in to aa.com and re-saved my contact email and phone.  This updated the reservation and I then got an email from BA 1 minute later showing the 6-digit BA locator and I was able to add it to my BA iphone app using that locator.  Unexpected but it worked.